# Data Storage and Export From Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, matrix

Here is background information to the problem I am encountering:

1) output is a cell array, each cell contains a matrix of size = 1024 x 1024, type = double

2) labelbout is a cell array which is the identical to output, except that each matrix has been binarized.

3) I am using the function regionprops to extract the mean intensity and centroid values for ROIs (there are multiple ROIs in each image) for each cell of output

4) props is a 5 x 1 struct with 2 fields (centroid and mean intensity)

The problem: I would like to take the mean intensity values for each ROI in every matrix and export to excel. Here is what I have so far:

```
for i = 1:size(output,2)
    props = regionprops(labelboutput{1,i},output{1,i},'MeanIntensity','Centroid');  
end 

for i = 1:size(output,2)
    meanValues = getfield(props(1:length(props),'MeanIntensity'));
end 

writetable(struct2table(props), 'advanced_test.xlsx');
```

There seem to be a few issues:

1) my getfield command is not working and gets the error: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions"

2) when the information is being stored into props, it overwrites the values for each matrix. How do I make props a 5 x n (where n = number of cells in output)?

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) my getfield command is not working and gets the error: "Index exceeds matrix dimensions"

An easier way to get numeric values out of the same field in an array of structs, as an array is:  `[structArray.fieldName]`.  In your case this will be:

```
  meanValues = [props.MeanIntensity];
```

> 2) when the information is being stored into props, it overwrites the values for each matrix. How do I make props a 5 x n (where n = number of cells in output)?
>   One option would be to preallocate an empty cell of the necessary dimensions and then fill it in with your `regionprops` output.  Like this:

```
props = cell(size(output,1),1);
for k = 1:size(output,2)
    props{k} = regionprops(labelboutput{1,k},output{1,k},'MeanIntensity','Centroid');
end

for k = 1:size(output,2)
    meanValues = [props{k}.MeanIntensity];
end
...
```

Another option would be to combine your loops so that you can use your matrix data before it is overwritten.  Like this:

```
for i = 1:size(output,2)
    props = regionprops(labelboutput{1,i},output{1,i},'MeanIntensity','Centroid');  
    meanValues = [props.MeanIntensity];

   % update this call to place props in non-overlapping parts of your file (e.g. append)
   % writetable(struct2table(props), 'advanced_test.xlsx');
end
```

The bad thing about this second one is it has a file I/O step right inside your loop which can really slow things down; not to mention you will need to curtail your writetable call so it places the resulting table in non-overlapping regions of `'advanced_test.xlsx'`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! 

There is one change I want to make to the data, however, I am unsure how to implement it...

Currently, each cell in meanValues contains all the mean intensities. Thus, meanValues is a 1 x n (number of cells in output) cell array. I would like to have mean intensities printed in the columns of meanValues so that it would be a 5 (the number of ROIs in each matrix) x 4 array. Please let me know if I am being unclear. 

Thanks again!!!!

Comment: To I figured it out! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Sorry, just seeing this now.  I am glad you got it worked out!  Did you use `reshape` or something else?  Can you accept this answer if you are all set now?  I think you get a few points for it as well.